# Error when calling AFNetworking getPath

Tags: objective-c, ios6, afnetworking

I use AFNetworking for communicating with my web service, with the following code:

```
-(NSMutableDictionary*)getData:(NSString*)userID{

__block NSMutableDictionary *data;
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc]initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://webservice.com/api/"]];

[httpClient setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];
[httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];

[httpClient getPath:@"data" parameters:@{@"type":@"1", @"id":userID}
success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id JSON) {
    data = (NSMutableDictionary *) JSON;
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error occured!");
}];

return data;
```

}

Calling this method gives me the following error:
**[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'**

What does this mean? It´s not a failure so I´m not sure if it the web service call that goes wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that userID is not nil.

It is usually a good practice to log request payload and server response first to make sure that everything works as it supposed to.

Comment: There's also an AFNetworkActivityLogger you should check out - https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworkActivityLogger

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that you are casting your `JSON` variable to an `NSDictionary`. Here's the line I'm referring to:

```
data = (NSMutableDictionary *) JSON;
```

Instead you might want to try:

```
[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:JSON
                                options:kNilOptions
                                  error:&error];
```

And then save that to your `data` variable.

Comment: AFNetworking will automatically parse the `NSData` into an array or dictionary for using in that callback block.